# Maven: create a jar executing my java files, instead of containing them

Tags: java, maven

I want to create a jar file containing downloaded and processed Internet files. And I want to do it using Mave. So, instead of compiling my .java classes and create a jar with them, I want to *execute* my code (who gets the files, process them, etc) and then package the resulting files in a jar.

How is the best approach to accomplish this? Maybe a plugin?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** What I want is a Maven project that, when you execute mvn:package or mvn:install finally you get a jar file, as always. The difference is that this files must be downloaded and processed by my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Maven Exec plugin](http://mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to extend the behavior of maven, you write a plugin. maven.apache.org and other related locations will tell you what you need to know. For simple things you can use the maven-antrun-plugin or the groovy-maven-plugin and script.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right. Do you know if this plugin must be an external maven project? What I prefer is all my code in the project.

Comment: I think it has to be a separate maven project.

Comment: you can probably make it a separate sub-module in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I actually like the one-jar plugin for creating executable jars. I have a blog post that explains step by step what do if you are using maven or ant: [Creating Executable Jars](http://www.chrisjordan.ca/node/18)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly my problem. I don't want to get an executable jar file. I want to execute my code and get a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be a job for the [maven-dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) which can download artifacts. After downloading you can do whatever you like with them.